# Is there a way to grant allies the benefit of teamwork feats without having that feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

So a friend of mine can take a few teamwork feats that would really help him in combat like [Enfilading Fire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enfilading-fire-combat-teamwork) or [Coordinated Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/coordinated-shot-combat-teamwork) but because of the prerequisites that would serve no purpose for melee characters (Point Blank Shot, Precise Shot, etc) it's pretty impractical for us to take them. Is there an easier way to grant an ally the benefits of a teamwork feat that doesn't include having it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to split the cost of a [***ring of tactical precision***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-tactical-precision) (*Ultimate Equipment* 175) (11,000 gp; 0 lbs.) or two. Your buddy wears the *ring* for an hour, picks one of his teamwork feats, and gives the *ring* to you. While you're wearing the ring, for 1 day you can use that teamwork feat your buddy picked. (He doesn't lose the feat or anything, though.) You benefit from the teamwork feat your buddy picked, but can only benefit from the teamwork feat in conjunction with your buddy. (For instance, were the fighter that possesses a teamwork feat to have imbued two *rings* with the same teamwork feat and given one to the cleric and and another to the rogue, the fighter and the rogue in tandem could use the teamwork feat as could the fighter and the cleric, but not the cleric and the rogue.)

Much more expensive—and annoying—is the ***helmet of the golden general*** (*Ultimate Equipment* 357-8) (62,000 gp; 3 lbs.), an intelligent item which can grant the wearer the creator's choice of three teamwork feats, which "[t]he wearer can use... as if [they] were on his feat list," presumably ignoring prerequisites entirely. The feats are chosen when the *helmet*'s created and can't be changed afterward. But during battle the *helmet* provides constant verbal color commentary and condescending coaching. I suggest immediately somehow muting the central ruby where the words come out.

Answer (score 2):

There are several abilities your ally could take to treat you as having the Teamwork feats.  The [inquisitor's Solo Tactics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Solo-Tactics-Ex-) class ability, the [fighter's Fighter's Tactics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Advanced-Weapon-Training) advanced weapon training, the cavalier's Tactician ability, and the [Holy Tactician archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/holy-tactician) paladin's Battlefield Presence class feature all work to give the user the ability to use Teamwork Feats their allies don't have (Solo Tactics and Fighter's Tactics just let the user pretend you have the feat, Tactician and Battlefield Presence actually temporarily give you the feat).  I'm sure there are more out there, those are just the ones I'm most familiar with.